# Windows10 git clone https://github.com/ktbyers/netmiko&#8221 Fatal error

Tags: git

I'm getting a lot of ssl errors following these instructions (https://www.jaacostan.com/2018/09/how-to-install-netmiko-on-windows.html) to install python with netmiko on Windows 10 on our corp network.

I know our browser has Aries Root cert, I did download it to my desktop but don't know what to do with it yet.

I'm stuck with this error in git bash now:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/ktbyers/netmiko&#8221
```

> [1] 7476
>   Cloning into 'netmiko'...
>
> 2 MINGW64 ~
>   $ cd fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/ktbyers/netmiko/': error:1425F175:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:inappropriate fallback

How can I fix this?

Comment: provide `git --version`?

Comment: $ git --version
git version 2.20.1.windows.1

Comment: I just installed the latest windows ver today and selected all the defaults.

Answer (score 2):

After upgrading from windows 7 to 10, I got a similar issue and I solved it by doing something below.

In git bash, run the below commands

```
$ git config --global http.sslVerify false
$ git config --global http.sslBackend openssl
$ git config --global http.sslbackend schannel
$ git config --global http.sslVersion tlsv1.2
```

Now do the git clone and it works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

It happens to me every now and then when I try to push my commits to remote. What I do to solve it is to first remove the Github Credentials from Windows in `Control Panel > User Accounts > Credential Manager > Windows Credentials`:
[image: Windows Credential Manager]

Then I open Powershell or Cmd.exe as Administrator in the repository folder and execute a git command:

```
Execute "$ git push"
```

It will show the Github login page. After typing my username and password correctly it works.

[image: Github login page]

Answer (score -1):

If you are fine with it from the security point of view (like, it's a server you know... it's on a corporate lan, or whatever), you might tell git to disregard the certificate check when cloning:

```
git -c http.sslVerify clone blah blah
```

Not the best thing to do.... but will get rid of the error.

Comment: from git bash I get an error with this command  MINGW64 ~
$ git config http.sslVerify false
fatal: not in a git directory

Comment: where do i tell git this??? first time using this. github.com/ktbyers/netmiko&#8221  is NOT on our lan